How to Track countOfResponseBodyBytesReceived and countOfResponseBodyBytesAfterDecoding in React Native (Similar to iOS)?
In iOS (13.0+), NSURLSessionTaskMetrics provides properties such as:
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
open var countOfResponseBodyBytesReceived: Int64 { get }

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
open var countOfResponseBodyBytesAfterDecoding: Int64 { get }

countOfResponseBodyBytesReceived: This property represents the total number of bytes received from the server.
countOfResponseBodyBytesAfterDecoding: This property represents the size of the response body after it has been decoded
I am working on a React Native project and would like to achieve the same functionality using Axios.
Specifically, I need to:
Track the total bytes received during a network request (similar to countOfResponseBodyBytesReceived).
Calculate the size of the decoded response body (similar to countOfResponseBodyBytesAfterDecoding).
What is the best approach to achieve this in React Native?
Are there any libraries or techniques that can help me track these metrics.
Any code examples or advice would be greatly appreciated!

I think you need to use axios interceptor, More specifically to the response of the interceptor.
in header we have content-length that is countOfResponseBodyBytesReceived
(need to parse with parseInt)
for counting decoded bytes, you can use
  new Blob([response]).size;

to get active countOfResponseBodyBytesAfterDecoding
if you want to count them , then you need to make variable outside of interceptor and just sum all received information together
